# Are there any continuous functions for the Zariski topology other than polynomials?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, continuity

Let $X$ be an affine algebraic subset of the $n$-dimensional affine space $A^n$ over a field $k$, and $A$ the affine line, both equipped with the Zariski topology. Is it true that a continuous function $f: X\rightarrow A$ is always the restriction of a polynomial in $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ to $X$?

Comment: What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with? What kind of answer are you looking for: Basic approach, hint, explanation, something else? Where did you encounter this problem? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Shaun I realize now that it's not true. We only have to take $X=A$ and any one-to-one function is continuous for the Zariski topology. Is that right?

Comment: I don't know. ${}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The topology on the affine line is the cofinite topology, so *any* bijection $\mathbb{A}^1\to\mathbb{A}^1$ is continuous. Certainly not all of these are given by polynomials, in general.